# Laravel 8 can't run Artisan::call('migrate', ['--force' => true])

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm creating Laravel installation wizard in Laravel 8 but I have a problem when I run the

```
Artisan::call('migrate', ['--force' => true])
```

When I execute the code, I got this message

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '' (SQL: create table `` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(191) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

I've tried to run migration with `php artisan migrate` and it works fine.
I think the problem is when creating `migrations` table, because I don't have any table with `migration` and `batch` field

Here is my `migrate()` function

```php
public function migrate()
{
    try {
        Artisan::call('migrate', ['--force' => true]);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return $this->response(
            "Failed to migrate tables. ".$th->getMessage(),
            'error'
        );
    }

    return $this->seed();
}
```

And this is my `seed()` function

```php
public function seed()
{
    try {
        Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--force' => true]);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return $this->response(
            "Failed to seed tables. ".$th->getMessage(),
            'error'
        );
    }

    return $this->response(
        "Successfully migrated and seeded tables.", 
        'success'
    );
}
```

Comment: check your migration folder if there are file that has no table name

Comment: @Doggo no, there are no file that has no table name

Comment: try adding `'migrations' => 'migrations'` in your `config -> database.php`

Comment: it's already exists

Comment: did you try to run `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: No, i haven't, because it's still in development. But i have tried `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: I can't help you with the problem anymore but here's some [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/artisan-call-migration-error)

Answer (score -1):

Artisan commands are relative to the folder your code is in. So if your not in the root folder of your application you have to specify the path to the migrations folder.

```
Artisan::call('migrate', array('--path' => '../app/database/migrations'));
```